# How do I find the count of overlapping properties in SQL/LINQ query between two tables?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have two tables. I'm only showing what's necessary here, but the two tables `ShoppingListA` and `ShoppingListB` have other properties and FK to different objects, but they both have a "`name`" property.

```
public class ShoppingListA
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ShoppingListB
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following DTO

```
public class ShoppingListDto
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Count {get; set;}
}
```

Further, I have a repo method which:

```
public async Task<List<ShoppingListDto>> GetShoppingLists()
{
       var shoppingListsA = await dbContext.ShoppingListA.Select(shoppingList => new ShoppingListDto
       {
           Id = shoppingList.Id,
           Name = shoppingList.Name,
        }).ToListAsync();

        var shoppingListsB = await dbContext.ShoppingListB.Select(shoppingList => new ShoppingListDto
       {
           Id = shoppingList.Id,
           Name = shoppingList.Name,
        }).ToListAsync()

      var allShoppingLists = shoppingListsA.Concat(shoppingListsB).ToList();
      return allShoppingLists;
}
```

When I return shoppingListsDto, I would like to know the count of how many times the same name appears across both tables. As an example.

let's say shoppingListA is:

```
[
  { 
    id: 2342352235,
    name: "Weekend Groceries"
  },
 { 
    id: 457457543,
    name: "Dinner party"
  },
]
```

let's say shoppingListB is:

```
[
  { 
    id: 3795794697,
    name: "BBQ stuff"
  },
 { 
    id: q845846q868,
    name: "Dinner party"
  },
]
```

then my GetShoppingLists method would return:

```
[
      { 
        id: 3795794697,
        name: "BBQ stuff",
        count: 1,
      },
     { 
        id: q845846q868,
        name: "Dinner party",
        count: 2,
      },
     { 
        id: 2342352235,
        name: "Weekend Groceries",
        count: 1,
      },
     { 
        id: 457457543,
        name: "Dinner party",
        count: 2,
      },
]
```

Comment: It easy, but without Id.

Answer (score 0):

To collect count of overlapping properties you just need grouping of joined tables.

```cs
var query =
    from a in dbContext.ShoppingListA
    join b in dbContext.ShoppingListB on a.Name equals b.Name
    group a by a.Name into g
    select ShoppingListDto
    {
        Id = // which ID?
        Name = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a sequence of similar items, and you want to make groups of these items, based on some common value, consider to use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0)

In your case: you want to make groups of Shopping Lists, where every Shopping List in one group has the same value for Property name.

```
var shoppingListGroups = shoppinlists.GroupBy(shoppingList => shoppingList.Name,

// parameter resultSelector: for every Name, and all ShopplingLists with this name
// make one new:
(name, shoppingListsWithThisName) => new
{
    Name = name,
    ShoppingListsI = shoppingListsWithThisName.Select(shoppingList => new
    {
        shoppingList.Id,
        Name = shoppingList.Name,
        Count = shoppingListsWithThisName.Count(),
    })
    .ToList(),
});
```

In words: from your sequence of ShoppingLists, make groups of ShoppingLists where every ShoppingList in each group has the same value for property ShoppingList.Name. From every group Name, and all ShoppingLists in this group (which all have the same Name), make one object, containing the common name, and a list of objects containing the Id, the Name and the number of elements in the group (= all ShoppintLists with this name).

IMHO this is fairly useless, you already know the Name, why would you repeat this name for all elements in the group, and why would you repeat the same count for every element in the groups. The following would be way more efficient:

```
"Grocery Shopping" has 3 elements with Ids {10, 23, 14}
"Dinner Party" has 2 elements with Ids {11, 12}
"BBQ stuff" has 1 element with Id {18}
```

If you want that, the query will be much easier:

```
var shoppingListGroups = shoppinlists.GroupBy(shoppingList => shoppingList.Name,

(name, shoppingListsWithThisName) => new
{
    Name = name,
    Ids = shoppingListsWithThisName.Select(shoppingList => shoppingList.Id).ToList(),
}
```

In words: make groups of ShoppingLists that have the same value for property ShoppingList.Name. For every Group make one object, that contains a Name and a list of Ids. The Name is the common Name for all ShoppingLists in the group; the list contains the Ids of all ShoppingLists in the group. Every List has a property `Count`, so you also know the total number of elements in each group.

The result will be more efficient and have a more natural feeling.